# running OpenGL on AML gpu clusters

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

I am trying to run rendering code based on OpenGL (https://glumpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/app-backends.html) on NC machines as part of an AML experiment.
No matter the back-end I try to use, I get errors when rendering.

Is OpenGL usage supported in AML?
Did anyone had similar experiences? Where you able to solve it?

thanks,
Emanuel

Comment: What do you mean by:
- "AML gpu cluster" -- compute instance (née notebook vm)? AMLCompute training cluster?, and;
- "render" do you want to view the OpenGL output in a notebook?

Comment: I am not using a notebook, just coding from vs studio or vs code. By GPU cluster I mean the GPU compute target I am using with the estimator. The rendered images are used in metrics calculations of object pose estimation (BOP metrics)

Answer (score 0):

I've never used OpenGL before, but I do see that it is [available in anaconda cloud](https://anaconda.org/auto/glumpy). My suggestion would be to build a Conda environment with the `glumpy` as a dependency. If that doesn't work you can build your own Docker image that has OpenGL installed and point AMLCompute to that image. [Here's some guidance on training environment set up.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-use-environments)